# How can my Rail3 app authenticate a request from my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, ios, ruby-on-rails-3, ipad

I'd like to add a tournament mode to my iPhone game and have a Rails 3 app track the tournament stats.  Basically, every time a match ends, the winner will be reported to my Rails 3 app using a post request like...

```
POST http://myrail3app.com/tourney/matchresults?winner=username
```

Obviously anyone could monitor the URL of the request being made and then make the same requests on their computer over and over again and cheat. So I'd like some way to authenticate the request on the Rails 3 app that ensures the request is coming from my iPhone app only.   Your thoughts?

Thanks so much for your wisdom!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the UDID as mentioned by Jason doesn't necessarily stop someone from reposting that in a desktop browser several times.

You have a few options, depending on how complex you want to get:

a) Public key encryption between your app and the rails server

- Read (iphone):
  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW9
- And (rails):
  http://stuff-things.net/2007/06/11/encrypting-sensitive-data-with-ruby-on-rails/

b) You can use a signature generation service, similar to how Facebook and Amazon handle singatures in their request.

- You provide a secret key to the app
  (most likely in your objective c code
  somewhere), and generate a HMAC
  signature based on all your
  parameters you are sending the app
  with your secret key (see
  http://www.ouah.org/ogay/hmac/). You
  then use the parameters sent across
  to generate another signature on the
  rails side, and compare the signature
  sent (eg in rails:
  `OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('sha256',
  message, key)`). If the 2 signatures
  are different, you know someone has
  tampered with the parameters.
- See Facebook
  (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)
  and Amazon
  (http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/2007-05-01/SQSDeveloperGuide/SummaryOfAuthentication.html)
  for an example on how to do this.

c) Depending on whether you want to share other data between your apps and your rails server, you can implement an Oauth provider on the rails side.

- Read (rails):
  http://stakeventures.com/articles/2007/11/26/how-to-turn-your-rails-site-into-an-oauth-provider
- And (iphone):
  http://davidquail.com/2009/12/07/oauth-authorization-callback-on-the-iphone-with-webview/

Comment: Thanks, Dominic, so helpful! Question about the HMAC approach, would it require the parameters being sent to be different every time a request is made in order for it to be secure? In other words, if the only data I was using to create the signature was the secret key and the username, then all the requests coming from a single user would be same every time, which could then be forged, correct?

Comment: Send a timestamp with the username. Eg: An epoch value http://mysite.com?username=foo&timestamp=1303268516&signature=abc123

Comment: Btw, you are sending the signature that has been signed by the secret key. The person trying to tamper with the parameters will have to know the secret key if they want to change a parameter (by changing the parameters and regenerating a new signature based on the new params & secret key). Just make sure they dont have access to the secret key yeah?

Answer (score 0):

you can just make the site only respond to a select list of iphone id's

```
NSString *deviceUDID = [myDevice uniqueIdentifier];
```

Comment: Couldn't a user just inspect a post request coming from their phone and then create a forgery from their computer?

Comment: absolutely. But that can happen with any application. If you want to encrypt the communication between the app and server that is possible too. But nothing is impenetrable. You just have to weigh the work involved in build for that sort of thing, and the likelyhood and issues with the forgery. You can probably implement a webservice over SSL, but that is a little outside my reach just yet.